# Can I use the Samsung Official Sources to build Ubuntu Touch on Samsung Galaxy SII i9100?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I would like to know if I can use official Android Jelly Bean sources from Samsung, for the GS2 i9100, from  [Samsung Open Source Release Center](http://opensource.samsung.com), to build a port of Ubuntu touch, despite the CyanogenMod 10.1 sources, in the official porting guide.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu touch bases on CyanogenMod 10.1 so you should use [CM kernel](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_samsung_smdk4210) for smdk4210 board that's i9100 built over. Also, don't forget to add Ubuntu Touch [specific changes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting#Kernel) to you defconfig in /arch/arm/configs/cm_i9100_defconfig